# Preserving geometry types when using st_intersection from sf package in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to get accustomed to using the `sf` package in R.

Currently, I am trying to clip a shapefile of all zip codes in the US to the border of the state of Utah. I have downloaded a shapefile for the Utah border and a shapefile of all zip code tabulation areas in the US and matched their projection information.

I found that creating a clip from two data files using `st_intersects()` followed by `st_intersection()` works well. `st_intersects()` saves only the zip codes that intersect with the border of Utah, then `st_intersection()` should clip the zip codes that touch or intersect with the Utah border to the exact Utah border.

When I run the `st_intersects()` command on the zip code file, the result preserves the multipolygon geometries of all of the zip codes. When I run `st_intersection()`, it creates a new sf object that has a mix of geometries - points, polygons, and multipolygons. I want the resulting sf file to only have multipolygons. I was able to remove the point geometries using this code:

```
zips_utah <- zips_utah %>%
  filter(st_geometry_type(.) != "POINT")
```

However, I still have an sf object with a mix of multipolygons and polygons. When I try to cast the polygons to multipolygons using `st_cast()`, I get this error:

```
only first part of geometrycollection is retainedError in st_cast.POINT(x[[1]], to, ...) : 
  cannot create MULTIPOLYGON from POINT
```

It seems that points still exist in the geometries of of my zip code shapefile, perhaps under the guise of "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION"? When I check the geometry type using `unique(st_geometry_type(zips_utah))`, this is the result I get:

```
[1] MULTIPOLYGON       POLYGON           
[3] GEOMETRYCOLLECTION
18 Levels: GEOMETRY POINT LINESTRING ... TRIANGLE
```

My understanding is that I cannot save the resulting clipped zip code sf object to a shapefile unless I first convert all the geometries to the same type. When I try to save the clipped zip code file using `st_write()`, I get the following error:

```
Error 1: Attempt to write non-polygon (POINT) geometry to POLYGON type shapefile.
```

I am wondering:

1. How do I preserve geometry types when running `st_intersection`?
2. Secondarily, does anyone have good resources on how the `sf` package handles geometries and mixed geometry types? What is the usefulness of this?

Comment: Are the zip code and Utah border shapefiles available somewhere so we can play with them?

Comment: Try `st_collection_extract(x, "POLYGON")` where x is your geometrycollection resulting from the st_intersection.

Comment: @StewartMacdonald - The Utah boundary shapefile was downloaded from https://gis.utah.gov/data/boundaries/citycountystate/. The Zip Code Tabulation Areas were downloaded from https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html.

Comment: @TimSalabim - Your approach appears to have worked perfectly. Upon investigating the resulting clipped Utah shapefile and the raw zip code shapefile in QGIS, the clip looks good. Thank you!